# php function filtration for input form

Tags: php

I try to create a function to filter the input field after submit
database connection

```
include("includes/connect.php");
```

this function is like that

```
<?php
function filter($x){
    global $conn;
    $y=strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$x))));
}
?>
```

Form

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="txt_name">
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">    
</form>
```

Code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
   $name= filtration($_POST['txt_name']);
   echo $name;
}
?>
```

When i try to print the $name after filtration i don't have any result

i try to do that

```
strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(htmlentities($x)))
```

and i have an output

but for me i want to use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

how can i solve this problem??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to return the value from your function. :)

```
function filter($x) {
    // do the cleaning of your string
    return $y; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    $name= filtration($_POST['txt_name']);
```

with

```
    $name= htmlspecialchars(filter_var(trim($_POST['txt_name']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING), ENT_QUOTES );
```